# Spinning icon next to mouse cursor while tooltip is loading (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, position, jquery-hover

I have a unique situation where I'd like to display a **spinning loading icon** next to the mouse cursor.

This icon will display when a user hovers their mouse over a `div`. A tooltip will then display after a delay of `1300ms`. The spinning icon will display while the tooltip is being delayed, and then hide once the tooltip is displayed.

I have written some code using the [jquery-ui .position extension](https://jqueryui.com/position/), and have achieved what I need. However, once the tooltip is displayed and the spinning icon disappears, it comes right back when I move the mouse cursor. I'd like the icon to disappear permanently until the mouse is moved outside of the div.

---

**FOR EXAMPLE:**
I have created a [jsfiddle of this scenario](https://jsfiddle.net/anthonycam/wpba0os3/7/).

Hold your mouse cursor over the `Product Info Container`. You will see the spinning icon appear, and after 1300ms, the tooltip will display and the spinning icon will disappear. But once you move the mouse again, the icon comes back.

---

How can I hide the spinning icon for good, once the tooltip is displayed, regardless if I move the mouse or not?

jQuery code I have so far is below.

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {
    var delay = 1300;
    var timeout;
    $('.product-bottom-info-container').hover(
        function(e) {
            var that = $(this);
            timeout = setTimeout(function() {
                that.find('.product-custom-tooltip-container').css({
                    display: 'inline-block',
                    position: 'fixed',
                    zIndex: '5000',
                    margin: '10px',
                    whiteSpace: "nowrap"
                }).position({
                    my: "right+10 center",
                    at: "center",
                    of: e,
                    collision: "fit flip"
                });

                $('.mouse-spinner').hide();
            }, delay);
        }, 
        function() {
            clearTimeout(timeout);
            $(this).find('.product-custom-tooltip-container').hide();
            $('.mouse-spinner').hide();
        }
    ).mousemove(function(e) {
        $('.mouse-spinner').css({
            display: 'inline-block',
            position: 'fixed',
            zIndex: '5000',
        }).position({
            my: "left+10 top+12",
            at: "center",
            of: e,
            collision: "flip"
        });
    });
});
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a spinner css static part through class of your style-sheet and redefine it when tooltip is become active. Or you can check "timeout" as condition of the code inside mousemove function or you can set additional class also as condition of mousemove function execution. There is a lot of solutions to resolve you case.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I will play around with it, based on your info. Can you show me an example of one of these solutions?

Comment: Ok, only thing I needed to do was add $('.mouse-spinner').hide(); back to the hover function, as it was removed in your code. Otherwise, this works. Thanks man.